# Yii CListView Ajax пагинатор + History Back

Tags: ajax, php, yii, history

Имеется контроллер **pages**, **ActionIndex** рендерит страничку с виджетом **CListView**
Екшн Контроллера:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    model=new Pages();
    $this->render('index',array(
        'pages'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

Представление Index:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'viewData' => array( 'switch' => true ),
    'enableHistory'=>true, //включаем History back
    'id'=>'pages_list',
    'itemView'=>'_view',
    'template'=>'{pager}<br />{items}<br />{pager}',
));
```

Теперь собственно вопрос:
В пагинаторе у ListView ссылки выгледят в виде:

> http://localhost/pages/index/Pages_page/1/
> http://localhost/pages/index/Pages_page/2/
> http://localhost/pages/index/Pages_page/3/

Но в В адресной строке ссылка подставляется как - то совсем не коректно. А именно:

> http://localhost/pages/?/pages/index/Pages_page/3/=

И естественно, страница не перелистывается.
И если повторно перейти на любую другую страницу, ссылка уже будет в виде:

> http://localhost/pages/?/pages/index//pages/index/Pages_page/3///ajax/pages_list/Pages_page/4/=

На сколько я понимаю, ковырять надо в сторону настроек роутов в URLManager'е.
только не совсем понимаю, что именно.

Comment: какой сейчас конфиг роутов?

Answer (score 1):

Эм, а что стоит в .htaccess??

быть может RewriteBase / в помощь?

И еще

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    model=new Pages(); // тут правильно написано? просто тут опечатался? $model должно быть.
    $this->render('index',array(
        'pages'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

Скорее всего трабл в htaccess т.к.

```
?/pages/index/Pages_page/3/=
```

во первых знака **?** быть не должно + в конце стоит знак **=** что тоже бред. Все остальное формируется правильно, но не от корня сайта, так что кинь сюда файлик

Comment: символ **?** в начале ссылки и **=** в корце, появляются когда включаю HistoryBack. Если его отключить и отключить аякс в целом, то ссылки вормируются как надо.